# Removing Stopwords and hyperlinks from tweets in database

Tags: java, mysql, nltk, twitter4j

I want to remove all the hyperlinks and stopwords from tweets stored in MySQL database. Also the hyperlinks that doesnt start with with http://.

Comment: java != mysql  != nltk != twitter4j

Answer (score 2):

We can use regex to accomplish these tasks in java

### Remove StopWords

```
String.replaceAll(STOPWORD,"")
```

### Remove Hyperlinks

```
String.replaceAll("http[^\\s]+","")
```

### Remove URl's That don't start with http

```
String.replaceAll("www[^\\s]+","")
```